# How to create a sparse numpy array from a dictionary of indices for nonzero elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dictionary of indices corresponding to nonzero numbers, and want to write a function that creates an sparse array with nonzero elements at the given indices, with zeros in between.
Ex:

```py
{(0,0):2, (1,1):3}
```

would output to the following numpy array

```py
([[2,0], [0,3]])
```

What would be the simplest way to convert this dense dictionary into a sparse array?

Comment: The scipy sparse `dok` format uses a dictionary subclass with keys like this

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the only thing you need, you should know the dimensions for your output.

```
import numpy as np

d = {(0,0):2, (1,1):3}

S = 2
table = np.zeros((S,S))

for k,v in d.items():
    if d[k]:
        table[ k[0],k[1] ] = v

print(table)
```